# Unwanted sprite rotation in Corona SDK

Tags: coronasdk

I'm doing a kirby-esque type game and I'm having issues with my sprite rotating on during flight as well as falling. Once the sprite is tapped it rotates CCW slightly and then rises. When it begins falling it rotates CW more than the CCW rotation and never resets to its original angle. **Any** help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Try setting

```
sprite_object.isFixedRotation = true
```